# WebOS installation on Mac

Tags: webos

I have downloaded the SDK and VirtualBox for webOS and both are properly installed on Mac. Right now the problem is I can't open project made in webOS on my Mac. Can anyone tell simple steps to open the project on my Mac.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `palm-install` followed by `palm-launch`. See the [command line tools reference](https://developer.palm.com/content/resources/develop/command_line_tools.html).

I prefer [palm-run](https://github.com/dalmaer/palm-run), which automates a few commands.

Comment: hey thanks for the link but i used this link :-http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/webos/webos-sdk/ and my app started working on WebOS.